# How to sort a map by value and if two more value are same then sort these entries by keys?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Here is my code :

```
 Map<PassengerType,Integer> test=new HashMap<>();
            test.put(PassengerType.SENIOR_CITIZEN,1);
            test.put(PassengerType.KID,1);
            test.put(PassengerType.ADULT,1);

            List<Map.Entry<PassengerType, Integer>> list =
                    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<PassengerType, Integer>>(test.entrySet());

            Collections.sort(list, new ValueThenKeyComparator());

            list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is my custom comparator.

```
public class ValueThenKeyComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<PassengerType, Integer>> {

    public int compare(Map.Entry<PassengerType, Integer> a, Map.Entry<PassengerType, Integer> b) {
        //System.out.println(a.getValue()+" || "+b.getValue()+" :::"+a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue()));
        int valueCompare=a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
        if(valueCompare!=0){
            return valueCompare;
        }else{
           // System.out.println(a.getKey()+" || "+b.getKey()+" :::"+a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey()));
            return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
        }
    }

}
```

the Output should be :

```
ADULT=1
KID=1
SENIOR_CITIZEN=1
```

but i am getting this.

```
KID=1
ADULT=1
SENIOR_CITIZEN=1
```

Please help me with this...

i have tried using custom comparator but no luck. struggling with this from past 6+ hours.

Comment: Are you sure that your enum is properly ordered? Please add a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Your comparator works fine if your enum is declared properly (https://ideone.com/mEvkOf), so you have something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe you need to sort by enum name? `a.getKey().name().compareTo(b.getKey().name())`

Comment: In addition, you do not need to create a custom comparator: `Map.Entry.<PassengerType, Integer>comparingByValue().thenComparing(entry -> entry.getKey().name())`